# loot table data packs 1.13 Please HELP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On my 1.13 server I am trying to do a (what I'm calling) Mansion Run, with a special Loot Table prize. I set the data pack up as dictated by [this site](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_data_pack) and used [this site](http://minecraft.tools/en/loots.php) to generate the loot table, and it didn't work, so I looked at the table and realized that since the names of (just about EVERY block has changed that wouldn't work off the generator so I edited where I seen needed to be, and it sill isn't working. I'm not one to ask for help on this but, I'm at my ends wit here. I hope I format this correctly as its my first time

```
{
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:dark_oak_planks",
          "weight": 10,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 12
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:dark_oak_log",
          "weight": 9,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 5
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:melon_seeds",
          "weight": 10,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 4
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:diamond_sword",
          "weight": 5
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:diamond_sword",
          "weight": 1,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_nbt",
              "tag": "{display:{Name:\"Bane of Illigers\",Lore:[\"Created by the Greatest Weapon-Smith\", \"the Villighers could Muster\"]}},Enchantments:[{id:\"minecraft:sweeping\",lvl:3},{id:\"minecraft:unbreaking\",lvl:3},{id:\"minecraft:sharpness\",lvl:3},{id:\"minecraft:knockback\",lvl:2}]}"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:name_tag",
          "weight": 6
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:ender_chest",
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:glass",
          "weight": 8,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 12
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:red_wool",
          "weight": 8,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 8
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:stone_stairs",
          "weight": 8,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 8
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:emerald_ore",
          "weight": 4,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:cauldron",
          "weight": 5
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:white_carpet",
          "weight": 8,
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": 10
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try a shorter command. Nobody can debug this mess.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you were able to ever figure this out, but I was finally able to do it myself by escaping each key in the tag, and any place a double quote was used inside of the tag's string value. I was even able to change the color of the Lore text.

I do not know for certain, but it appears that you do not need to use set_count for all items.  If I just want one item dropped, then set_count does not appear to be necessary.

I was able to trouble shoot the issue by looking at the console output for the server.

```
{
    "type": "item",
    "name": "minecraft:diamond_sword",
    "weight": 1,
    "functions": [
        {
            "function": "set_name",
                "name": {
                    "text": "Bane of Illagers",
                    "color": "green",
                    "italic": "false"
                 }
        },
        {
            "function": "set_nbt",
            "tag": "{\"display\":{\"Lore\": [\"§fCreated by the Greatest Weapon-Smith\",\"§fthe Villagers could Muster.\"]},\"Enchantments\":[{\"id\":\"minecraft:sweeping\",\"lvl\":3},{\"id\":\"minecraft:unbreaking\",\"lvl\":3},{\"id\":\"minecraft:sharpness\",\"lvl\":3},{\"id\":\"minecraft:knockback\",\"lvl\":2}]}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to run set count functions on *ALL* items, otherwise it won't know how many it needs to give. Stone_stairs needs to be stone_brick_stairs. And this doesn't effect the code, but it should be Illager not Illiger. otherwise it seems fine.

a tip for finding issues in data packs: turn on the console in the launcher before you launch the game next time, the option can be found in the settings tab in the launcher. this opens a window in the launcher app when the game is launched that shows errors such as issues with loading files from data packs.

Comment: i tried the edits you suggested and it didn't work, the chests still come up empty and no errors i can see in console

Comment: try running it through a json validator and see if it corrects any errors does the data pack show as enabled when you do /datapack list?

Comment: it does show up as active when i run /datapack list, and i tried an online Validator and it apparently passed